# this is my code.. this code is working but get valu after slider not to work so how to work my slider after using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".select").click(function(){
    var cat_id=($(this).attr('id'));
    //alert(cat_id);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?php echo home_url();?>/other',
        data:'cat_id=' + cat_id,

        success:function(data){ 
            //alert(data);
            jQuery("#content").html(data);
            jQuery("#content").css("transform","translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)");
            return false;
        }
    });
 });
 });
</script>
```

This my code. It's working. `ajax` get all value but after slider is not working. slider is not slide. So how to slider my slider using after `ajax`?

Comment: Can we see the html body content (the code with `class="select"` and `id="content"`)??

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="<?php echo $cat_child->term_id; ?>" class="select"><li><?php echo  $cat_child->name;?></li></a>

Comment: <div class="content">"                   php code                 "</div>

Comment: its difficult to visualize the HTML markup with php script mixed in, can you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net